# ApplicationContext is null in an ApplicationAware class when lazy-initialization: true in springboot 3

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I want to initialize my beans lazily and hence enabled `spring.main.lazy-initialization=true` in application.properties.

I have a class called ApplicationContextProvider as below:

```
@Component
public class ApplicationContextProvider implements ApplicationContextAware {
private static ApplicationContext context;

public static <T> T getBean(String name, Class<T> aClass) {
    return context.getBean(name, aClass);
}

public static <T> T getBean(Class<T> aClass) {
    return context.getBean(aClass);
}

@Override
public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext ctx) throws BeansException {
    context = ctx;
}
}
```

when i call `ApplicationContextProvider.getBean(Environment.Class)` or any other class, the `ApplicationContext` is always null. So i get a null pointer exception.

Am I missing some configuration?

Please advise.

Comment: It is static, so if you aren't using Spring or calling this before Spring has finished ther is no garantuee this has been set. Also when using such a class this generally means you are doing things wrong in the first place.

Comment: oh ok, is there a way to know if context is set? I need this class as it is used in some static methods.

Comment: But why are you using this in the first place? You should be injecting dependencies not using this hack to look them up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due to the `getBean` methods being static, Spring has no way of knowing that  `ApplicationContextProvider` is being used. When lazy initialization is enabled, beans are only initialized when they're used. As Spring can't tell that you're using `ApplicationContextProvier`, it's never initialized and `setApplicationContext` is never called.

You could define a `LazyInitializationExcludeFilter` bean that excludes `ApplicationContextProvider` from lazy initialization. However, as has been said in the comments, a better solution would be remove the need for `ApplicationContextProvider` by using dependency injection instead.

Comment: Thank you. Understood. The reason why I need this static method is because its an existing implementation in my project. If I have to remove this, it would require a lot of changes. Ignoring this class from LasyInit is working.